# mysql query count consecutive positive numbers in a column

Tags: mysql, count, max

I have a table called "results" , like this :

```
 ID   -A- -B- -C- -D- -E- -F- 
 1   100 -76  34 -45 54  65
 2    34  -43  57 -12 13 -21
 3    104 -76  34 -45 -3  43
 4    100 -76  -4 -45 54  65
 5    34  -43  57 -12 13 -21
 6    104 -76  34 -45 -3  43
```

there are obviously more data, but i think this is enough to get the idea.

what i am trying to get, is the max count of the consecutive positive numbers in each column.

what would be the mysql query for that?

thank you for reading this.

Comment: What do you mean, "*the max count of the consecutive positive numbers*"?  Can you give an example?  Remember, tables are not stored in any particular order so the notion of "*consecutive*" is ill-defined in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: What have you already tried and what were your results? How did they differ from your desired result?

Comment: You will also need a column to determine the sort order.

Comment: in column A the count should be 6. in B 0, in C 3, in D 0, in E 2, in F 2. there's a column ID. the order by is by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea.  For each number in the column, add a flag to determine if it is the beginning of a sequence (which will be anything following a negative number).  Do a cumulative sum of this value to get a "sequence count".  Then, get the maximum of this value.  I am going to show the code for one column:

The only problem is the implementation, which requires multiple levels of correlated subqueries.  The first is to assign `SequenceStart`:

```
select r.*, rprev.A as prevA, rprev.B as prevB, rprev.C as prevC, rprev.D as prevD,
       (case when (rprev.A < 0 or rprev.A is NULL) then 1 else 0 end) as ASeqStart,
       (case when (rprev.B < 0 or rprev.B is NULL) then 1 else 0 end) as BSeqStart,
       (case when (rprev.C < 0 or rprev.C is NULL) then 1 else 0 end) as CSeqStart,
       (case when (rprev.D < 0 or rprev.D is NULL) then 1 else 0 end) as DSeqStart
from (select r.*,
             (select max(id)
              from results r2
              where r2.id < r.id
             )  previd
      from results r
     ) r left outer join
     results rprev
     on r.previd = rprev.id;
```

Now, getting the cumulative sum is tricky because you need the value twice.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow subqueries in views.  Although you can use the same query below, let me assume the results are put into a table `TempSeq`.  Then do the following to assign a sequence to each value.

```
select ts.*,
       sum(tsprev.ASeqStart) as ASeqId,
       sum(tsprev.BSeqStart) as BSeqId,
       sum(tsprev.CSeqStart) as CSeqId,
       sum(tsprev.DSeqStart) as DSeqId
from TempSeq ts join
     TempSeq tsprev
     on tsprev.id <= ts.id
group by ts.id;
```

Once again, let me assume that the results are stored in another temporary table, say `TempSeqId`, because you have to aggregate the results multiple times.  Here is an example for A:

```
select coalesce(max(seqlen), 0)
from (select ASeqId, count(*) as seqlen
      from TempSeqId
      where a > 0
     ) t
```

The condition on `a` might seem redundant.  But there is an off-by-one challenge -- most sequences will end with the final negative number.  For these, you can just subtract one from the count.  However, the final sequence may not end that way, and you would undercount it.  The coalesce is for the case where all values are negative.

At this point, let me say that the queries would actually be feasible (as a single query even) if the data structure were stored on a row with the `id` and `sequencename` and one value on a row.

EDIT:

The above reasoning is how I think about the problem.  In MySQL, you can approach this differently using variables.  The code is much simpler:

```
select MAX(APosCounter) as AMaxLen,
       MAX(BPosCounter) as BMaxLen,
       MAX(CPosCounter) as CMaxLen,
       MAX(DPosCounter) as DMaxLen
from (select r.*,
             @APosCounter := if(A > 0, @APosCounter + 1, 0) as APosCounter,
             @BPosCounter := if(B > 0, @BPosCounter + 1, 0) as BPosCounter,
             @CPosCounter := if(C > 0, @CPosCounter + 1, 0) as CPosCounter,
             @DPosCounter := if(D > 0, @DPosCounter + 1, 0) as DPosCounter
      from results r cross join
           (select @APosCounter := 0, @AMaxLen := 0,
                   @BPosCounter := 0, @BMaxLen := 0,
                   @CPosCounter := 0, @CMaxLen := 0,
                   @DPosCounter := 0, @DMaxLen := 0
            end) const
      order by id
     ) r
```

This code uses variable logic to keep the length of the "positive sequence length" on each row.  It then aggregates the data to get the maximum.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be233/3) is even a SQLFiddle to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: in the second select query from table TempSeq i get this "#1052 - Column 'ASeqStart' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros . . . Wow, it worked up to there ;)  I added the appropriate alias.

Comment: in the final query i get this "#1054 - Unknown column 'a' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros . . . `a` is your column.  All the other queries include `*`, so all your columns should be in the table.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff... i have to get back to this cause i am not getting the results expected. what i get is the total count of positive numbers and not the CONSECUTIVE COUNT. the result i get is the same as this... SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM results
WHERE a > '0'

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros . . . The definition of sequence start didn't look right.  I think it should be that the previous value is negative and the current is positive.

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros . . . Although I like the first approach, the reasoning really works better when you have window functions (that is, any other database).  I just added a second approach which is MySQL-specific and should work much better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  GREATEST(
sum(if (A <= 0, 0,1)),
sum(if (B <= 0, 0,1)),
sum(if (C <= 0, 0,1)),
sum(if (D <= 0, 0,1)),
sum(if (E <= 0, 0,1)),
sum(if( F <= 0, 0,1)) 
) FROM RESULT
```

Comment: @jaczes... what i get is the total count of positive numbers and not the CONSECUTIVE COUNT. the result i get is the same as this... SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM results WHERE a > '0'

Comment: i have misunderstood the question, it gives You max of all collumn positive sum.